# Generate PWM Signal in LTSpice

Tags: pwm, ltspice, pulse

How can I generate a 100KHz PWM Signal in Ltspice?
How do I calculate Ton and Tperiode?

Comment: Please edit your question, its unclear what your asking. If you want to modulate the signal, then you'll need a multiplier (as in comm modulate). If you want to generate 100kHz then please say so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 100kHz signal must change every 1/T seconds, or 0.00001s, If you want a square wave with a 50% duty cycle then the Tperiod sets the time that the signal will be on and Ton sets the time during that period or 'window' that the signal is at Von.

Calculate your period: 1/f=Tperiod
Calculate how long the signal is on for 50% of the time (symmetrical square wave) would be t*Duty cycle = Ton.

If your looking to generate a PWM signal then use a PULSE Voltage source with
a signal changing at 100kHz Tperiod is set to 0.00001s. The Ton will be half that for a 50% duty cycle, or 0.000005s. The rise and fall times may be left at zero. If you wanted a 20% duty cycle the Ton time would be 0.000002

Comment: Thank you so much, now it is clear to me. In retrospect, it is so logical.

Comment: If you like the answer, upvote and mark

Answer (score 4):

If you need this to serve your [previous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367426/qi-comm-signal-simulation-ltspice) question, you'll be needing a time-varying PWM. You can set a ramp voltage in LTspice like this:

```
PULSE(0 1 0 {0.99/f} {0.01/f} 0 {1/f})
```

which is a ramp from 0 to 1V, with period given by the frequency `f`. You could have used `{1/f}` for rise time and zero for fall and Ton, but that setting can have adverse effects in the dynamic range in long runs.

Then, you can find the best comparator for the job in `[Digital]/schmitt`. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200936/ltspice-how-to-create-pwm-with-rise-time/367832#367832) answer.