# How to make a pulse source with a changing duty cycle in LT spice?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, duty-cycle

[image: Attached is a super dummied down version of the circuit]I have a power electronic inverter, and I want to make the duty cycle of the PWM dependent on the ratio of "vout/vin", where vout is an AC power source.

Unfortunately, setting .param D= IF(V(vout)/V(vin) < 0.5, 1, 0) doesn't work. In fact, even just setting D to be a sine-wave source doesn't work.

Does this mean that LTSpice params need to be constant, and that a "control circuit" needs to be implemented to get something that can change on the fly?

Comment: You can sweep sources and use the sweeps value to set up other values.

Comment: @jonk would this mean setting up a sweep analysis, and then using the results from that to setup the other values?

Comment: Yes. If you provide sufficient details -- a reduced schematic that illustrates your issue well would be okay -- I can help. I don't have enough info now, though. And a sweep isn't necessarily the only way to go. It is just one of several.

Comment: A bit of shameful self-advertising, but maybe [these](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/367832/95619) can [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/367833/95619)? I'm sure there are others. In fact, I'm surprised you didn't see any when you wrote your question.

Comment: @RonaldB Your "IF" appears to want just 1 or 0 -- it digitizes the ratio. But your other words appear to suggest that you want a smooth duty cycle calculation, without it being digitized like that. Is this a switcher of some kind?

Comment: @jonk Hi jonk thanks for the reply. Currently I just want it to be able to calculate something on the fly returning simple values rather than additional calculations. Unfortunately it's not able to handle it.

Comment: @RonaldB Consider using a B-source. They allow full calculations.

Comment: @jonk thanks for helping, added a super simplified circuit.

Comment: @RonaldB The two links I provided deal with exactly this. Have you checked them?

Comment: @RonaldB I know your schematic is highly behavioral because (a) you don't have the (-) lead of the SW connected anywhere and (b) models are missing and parts really don't have any specifications. I get it better now. But what's confusing me is that you are using a cycled switch and an inductor between an AC source and a DC source. What's that about? In some sense, I might just agree with aconcernedcitizen that you refer to his examples. But I can't even know that much, as I'm not sure what the larger picture is. Might be an X-Y problem needing some other thoughts.